# Which of the following values are definitely the same in both the parent and child process?

Tags: c, pointers, process, fork, memory-address

Consider the program below.

```
int dataA[8];
int func(int i) {
 return i;
}
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
 int *dataB = malloc(1);
 fork();
 int *dataC = malloc(1);
 int (*func_ptr)(int i) = &func;
 return 0;
}
```

Which of the following values are definitely the same in both the parent and child process? Assume
that fork()does not fail.

1. &dataA
2. &dataB
3. &dataC
4. dataC
5. func_ptr
6. &func_ptr

The answer is 1,2,3,5,and 6. I am not sure why &dataC would be the same give that it was allocated after the fork.
Could someone help to explain what, in general, would cause the pointer address to be different in the child process?

Comment: `&dataC` is the address of the pointer on the stack. Typically, the stack layout is determined at compile time, so the address of `dataC` will be the same. But the value in `dataC` is whatever `malloc` returns at runtime. That *could* be different between parent and child.

Comment: I see. Had C been simply initialized as int C = 3, then am I right to say that C would be stored in the stack, and so &dataC would be different?

Comment: I'm afraid that question makes no sense. When you're talking about `C`, do you really mean `dataC`?

Comment: Yes I meant dataC.

Comment: In that case, `&dataC` would not be different. It would still be the address of the variable on the stack.

Comment: I see. What happens if dataC is only initialised in a random chance? (e.g. in both the parent and child process, generate a random integer, and initialise C if the random integer is greater than 10). Will this part of the stack layout be determined in compile time?

Comment: That's a good question, and in my experience, the answer is yes, the layout is still determined at compile time. You can test this with your compiler by looking at the assembly code in a debugger, or use the `-S` compiler option to output the assembly code.

Comment: Note that nothing in the C standard guarantees this behavior. In fact, there's nothing in the C standard about a stack. So the answer 1,2,3,5,and 6 is based on typical desktop implementations. It's not true in every conceivable implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I think the point of confusion is about the shared/not shared memory space.

If you fork a process the child will be a copy of the parent. The only difference in the child and the parent is the returned value for `fork`.
This means that the heap will also be in the same state.
So if after the fork the child and the parent do a call to `malloc` they will be the same address.
However they will not point to the *same* memory, this is beacuse the child does not share (on default) the memory with its parent.

So dispite that `dataC` having the *"same"* ptr value in both processes they both point to different **physical** addresses.
In fact all pointer will.

You can test this with minor changes to your program.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int dataA[8];
int func(int i) {
 return i;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int *dataB = malloc(1);

    *dataB = 2;
    dataA[1] = 7;

    int pid = fork();

    int *dataC = malloc(1);
    int (*func_ptr)(int i) = &func;

    printf("pid = %d\ndataA = %p\ndataB = %p\ndataC = %p\nfunc_ptr = %p\n", pid, &dataA, dataB, dataC, func_ptr);

    if (pid != 0) {
        *dataC = 5;
        dataA[0] = 3;
    }

    printf("pid = %d\n*dataB = %d\n*dataC = %d\ndataA[0] = %d\n", pid, *dataB, *dataC, dataA[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

which will produces something like:

```
pid = 26563
dataA = 0x404060
dataB = 0x1275e70
dataC = 0x1275e90
func_ptr = 0x401146
pid = 26563
*dataB = 2
*dataC = 5
dataA[0] = 3
pid = 0
dataA = 0x404060
dataB = 0x1275e70
dataC = 0x1275e90
func_ptr = 0x401146
pid = 0
*dataB = 2
*dataC = 0
dataA[0] = 0
```